# python 3.2 syntax error: invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax

can any one find the syntax error in this python 3.2 code?

```
import math
import numpy

vinf = 10
vfr = 4
x = numpy.linspace(-10,10,50)
y = numpy.linspace(-10,10,50)
a = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(x),len(y)))
b = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(x),len(y)))
u = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(x),len(y)))
v = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(x),len(y)))
p = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(x),len(y)))
s = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(x),len(y)))


for i in range (0,len(x)):
    for j in range (0,len(y)):
        a[i][j]=x[i]
        b[i][j]=y[j]


for i in range (0,len(x)):
    for j in range (0,len(y)):

        v[i][j] = (vfr/(2*math.pi))*math.pow((b[i][j]+.0047)/(a[i][j]+.05)+(b[i][j]+.0517)/(a[i][j]+.2084)+(b[i][j]-.0271)/(a[i][j]+.2084)+(b[i][j]+.0583)/(a[i][j]+.525)+(b[i][j]-.0228)/(a[i][j]+.525)+(b[i][j]+.0242)/(a[i][j]+.8417)+(b[i][j]-.0087)/(a[i][j]+.8417),-2)*((b[i][j]+.0047)/(math.pow(a[i][j]+.05,2)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0047)/(a[i][j]+.05),2)))+(b[i][j]+.0517)/(math.pow(a[i][j]+.2084,2)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0517)/(a[i][j]+.2084),2)))+(b[i][j]-.0271)/(math.pow(a[i][j]+.2084,2)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]-.0271)/(a[i][j]+.2084),2)))+(b[i][j]+.0583)/(math.pow(a[i][j]+.525,2)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0583)/(a[i][j]+.525),2)))+(b[i][j]-.0228)/(math.pow(a[i][j]+.525,2)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]-.0228)/(a[i][j]+.525),2)))+(b[i][j]+.0242)/(math.pow(a[i][j]+.8417,2)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0242)/(a[i][j]+.8417),2)))+(b[i][j]-.0087)/(math.pow(a[i][j]+.8417,2)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0087)/(a[i][j]+.8417),2))))
        u[i][j] = vinf+(vfr/(2*math.pi))*math.pow((b[i][j]+.0047)/(a[i][j]+.05)+(b[i][j]+.0517)/(a[i][j]+.2084)+(b[i][j]-.0271)/(a[i][j]+.2084)+(b[i][j]+.0583)/(a[i][j]+.525)+(b[i][j]-.0228)/(a[i][j]+.525)+(b[i][j]+.0242)/(a[i][j]+.8417)+(b[i][j]-.0087)/(a[i][j]+.8417),-2)*(1/((a[i][j]+.05)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0047)/(a[i][j]+.05),2)))+1/((a[i][j]+.2084)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0517)/(a[i][j]+.2084),2)))+1/((a[i][j]+.2084)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]-.0271)/(a[i][j]+.2084),2)))+1/((a[i][j]+.525)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0583)/(a[i][j]+.525),2)))+1/((a[i][j]+.525)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]-.0228)/(a[i][j]+.525),2)))+1/(a[i][j]+.8417)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0242)/(a[i][j]+.8417),2)))+1/((a[i][j]+.8417)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0087)/(a[i][j]+.8417),2))))
        p[i][j] = 1-math.pow(math.sqrt(math.pow(u[i][j],2)+math.pow(v[i][j],2)),2)

file = open("data.dat","w")
file.write('title = "Driven Cavity"\r\n')
file.write('variables = "x", "y", "u", "v", "p"\r\n')
file.write('ZONE T="All"\r\n')
file.write(' I={}'.format(len(x)))
file.write(' J={}'.format(len(x)))
file.write(' K=1')
file.write(' ZONETYPE=Ordered\r\n')
file.write(' DATAPACKING=POINT\r\n')

for i in range (0,len(x)):
    for j in range (0,len(y)):
        file.write('{}\t'.format(a[i][j]))
        file.write('{}\t'.format(b[i][j]))
        file.write('{}\t'.format(u[i][j]))
        file.write('{}\t'.format(v[i][j]))
        file.write('{}\t\n'.format(p[i][j]))

file.close()
```

the error says it is at the end of the u[i][j]= line
it is probably a parenthesis or something i just cant see it.
ive been working on this since 5 pm last night it is now 3:40 pm the next day.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the traceback/error message and also identify the line you mention with a comment in your source listing.

Comment: It would probably also help to use a text editor that highlights matching parentheses.

Comment: More helpful would be PEP 8 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), this line has **734** characters in it

Comment: ok problem solved thankyou very much for all of your help and especially to fferen for his/her suggestion for some reason that never eve crossed my mind

Answer (score 2):

extra `)` at the end of line, replace that line with this :

```
u[i][j] = vinf+(vfr/(2*math.pi))*math.pow((b[i][j]+.0047)/(a[i][j]+.05)+(b[i][j]+.0517)/(a[i][j]+.2084)+(b[i][j]-.0271)/(a[i][j]+.2084)+(b[i][j]+.0583)/(a[i][j]+.525)+(b[i][j]-.0228)/(a[i][j]+.525)+(b[i][j]+.0242)/(a[i][j]+.8417)+(b[i][j]-.0087)/(a[i][j]+.8417),-2)*(1/((a[i][j]+.05)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0047)/(a[i][j]+.05),2)))+1/((a[i][j]+.2084)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0517)/(a[i][j]+.2084),2)))+1/((a[i][j]+.2084)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]-.0271)/(a[i][j]+.2084),2)))+1/((a[i][j]+.525)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0583)/(a[i][j]+.525),2)))+1/((a[i][j]+.525)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]-.0228)/(a[i][j]+.525),2)))+1/(a[i][j]+.8417)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0242)/(a[i][j]+.8417),2)))+1/((a[i][j]+.8417)*(1+math.pow((b[i][j]+.0087)/(a[i][j]+.8417),2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Break the line up into several smaller operations so that the error is isolated.  Try just starting with `u[i][j] = 0` and successively add small pieces of the full line until the error happens, then you'll know where to look for it.

Comment: This really ought to be a comment

Answer (score 1):

Pasting it into `vim` and highlighting the last character shows that, at the least, there is an extra close paren.  However, I would suggest breaking this into a number of lines so that it is possible to debug it by hand.  Lines that long are not a good idea in any language, for readability reasons.